# How to remove all text in .txt before writing C#

Tags: c#, text

How to remove everything from text file before writing?

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\text.txt", Environment.NewLine + item);
```

This is how I am writing to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) instead of `AppendAllText`

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\text.txt", item);
```